# Impose $f$ is function of $x$ in MAPLE

Tags: functions, maple

I am a bit new in MAPLE and I was trying to write a function of $x$.

I define a function:

$W:=W_{d_{{\it ij}}}\,W_{f_{{\it ij}}}$

I would just like to write in MAPLE  $diff(W,x)$  and get:
$ \left( {\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}x}}W_{d_{{\it ij}}} \left( x \right) 
 \right) W_{f_{{\it ij}}} \left( x \right) +W_{d_{{\it ij}}} \left( x
 \right) {\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}x}}W_{f_{{\it ij}}} \left( x \right) $

Instead I get just $0$ as a result. I know it is correct of MAPLE of giving me $0$ but how can I tell it that $W_D$ and $W_F$ are functions of $x$?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the error. It was pretty easy. I needed to add the dependency from $x$ (of course).

Basically to get what I wanted I needed to write the function as:

$W:=W_{d_{{\it ij}}} \left( x \right) W_{f_{{\it ij}}} \left( x \right) $

In this way I get the result:

$ \left( {\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}x}}W_{d_{{\it ij}}} \left( x \right) 
 \right) W_{f_{{\it ij}}} \left( x \right) +W_{d_{{\it ij}}} \left( x
 \right) {\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}x}}W_{f_{{\it ij}}} \left( x \right) $

I hope it will help someone else.